# Joomla - Show logged username in top menu

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

How can I show the logged username in the top menu of Joomla.
I have the following code but don't know where to insert it.

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser(); echo $user->name;
```

Comment: in backend or fronend?

Comment: front end.In top menu part

Answer (score 2):

The login module can display a greeting. You just have to **go to Extensions > Module Manager > Login** whatever you have the login module display name

https://docs.joomla.org/Customising_the_Login_Form_module

Comment: "Error
Edit state is not permitted."
cannot edit login form module, the above error coming.

Comment: you have unlock the error button or you do not have superuser access?

Answer (score 0):

First check which theme currently activated in your joomla project.

For e.g If currently default theme `"protostar"` in joomla 3.x activated then

1. Go to `"\PROJECT_FOLDER\templates\protostar"`.
2. Open `index.php` file.
3. Put code after `<div class="body">` tag start and add your code in your desire position.

Use below code.

```
<?php
$user =& JFactory::getUser(); 
echo $user->name;
?>
```

Comment: I did like that but position is not coming properly

Comment: ohh ok. then you can try to put in position-0 which exist in <header> tag

Comment: can you please add an example?

Comment: I have no joomla setup right now. But I am suggesting you as I have worked on same before. You can istall extension "Flexi Custom Code" and from admin position-0 you can add your code.

Comment: Humm. Good one. @Josef